# AngularJS $http.post

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am trying to do an $http.post and get the response, I tried in several ways but I can't get it working.
The data I am sending (userData) is an json object.

```
 $http.post(url, userData)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('post success');
        console.log('data');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('status');
        console.log(status);
        console.log('headers');
        console.log(headers);
        console.log('config');
        console.log(config);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('post error');
        console.log('data');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('status');
        console.log(status);
        console.log('headers');
        console.log(headers);
        console.log('config');
        console.log(config);
    });
```

And I am getting a 404 in status.

Thank you

Comment: Means requested URL does not exists. Give us more info so we can help you.

Comment: I am sure the URL exists. I make a wrong call like this
<code>
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    data: userData,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
   }) .success(function(data) {
    console.log('post success');
    console.log('data');
    console.log(data);
   }).error(function(data) {
    console.log('post error');
    console.log('data');
    console.log(data);
   });
<code>
and the error is different is not 404, is 415 Unsupported Media Type, which is correct, because the userData is supposed to be json.

Comment: Without having more code I cannot give you any useful help. Either URL is not supporting POST method or some weird response from server.

Comment: Debugging with firebug I realized that the error in the console (when I show the status) is 404, but in the .Net is another error, 405 Method Not Allowed.
I am running a server with nodejs (with express and cors) calling an external http service.

Comment: You are probably trying to get to a GET service via a POST request. Try to change $http.post to $http.get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "405 Method not allowed" response is because your browser is doing a "preflight" OPTIONS method request via angular $http and your server doesn't support it. There are a bunch of prerequisite responses to enable CORS. If you have access to the server, you can add support for it. One option is to use nginx as a front-end proxy with this kind of configuration:

http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Read the comments--they are really informative.

Also: see "Preflighted Requests" here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thank you very much @Brian. The server doesn't support CORS, but I will try to figure out how to do it with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

404 means that the URL you're sending the request to does not exist.

If you're using a sub-directory like `mysite.com/angular-site`, and you set the URL here to a relative path like "/url/to/api" - you will get to "`mysite.com/url/to/path`" instead of the correct "`mysite.com/angular-site/url/to/path`".

So pay attention to that, it might be the problem.

Comment: I am realizing that the hearders attributes are different when works, and when it doesn't. I am trying to change that with angularjs.